# Getting a field having `text` type

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Class `Issue` inherits from `ActiveRecord` (ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux], Rails 3.2.13). Within this class I attempt to perform the following select:

```
results = Issue.find_by_sql("select id, notes from mydb.issues;")
results.each do |r|
  puts r.notes.class.name
end
```

The output is `NilType` in every line.

The field `notes` is of type `text` (MySQL, Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2). The is some text in this field, I can see it MySQL Workbench.

Why does it happen? How to access such a field correctly?

Comment: Why do you specify the database name?

Comment: Anything in the Issue class that appears relevant?

Comment: Is it returning NilType or NilClass? Can you include a 'where notes is not null' and see if it is returning the same message?

Comment: @Frederick Cheung thanks for the pointer. It turns out that `Issue` class delegates `notes` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the pointers provided by @Frederick Cheung and @Salil, I've found that `Issue` class has the following definition:

```
delegate :notes, :notes=, :to => :current_journal, :allow_nil => true
```

Certainly, changing the name `notes` in the resulting recordset solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have added `notes` as a [`attr_protected`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001806)

```
  class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_protected :notes
  end

  issue = Issue.new("notes" => "Some notes here")
  issue.notes # => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrongly, you have already select all the notes from your table, now your results object contains all the notes in an array, so you have to only loop through it :

If you have another 'Note' model, than you have to do this :

```
results = Issue.find_by_sql("select * from mydb.issues;")
results.each do |r|
  puts r.notes.class.name
end
```

or if you have notes field in your issues table than you should do this :

```
results = Issue.find_by_sql("select notes from mydb.issues;")
results.each do |r|
  puts r.class.name
end
```

Hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: r.class.name would return 'Issue', r.notes.class.name would just return 'String'.

Comment: The recordset contains some other fileds as well. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to retrieve a single column from the database is using [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck). If the following line returns `false`

```
Issue.pluck(:notes).any?{ |v| !v.nil? }
# or, since you're using MySQL:
Issue.where('notes IS NOT NULL').pluck(:notes).present?
```

it's likely that you have some serious problem (database connection which points to another database, f.e.)

Comment: The recordset contains other fields as well, and the actual SQL is very complex. I've reduced it just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: If the SQL is complex it's likely that the problem is due the SQL complexity, so it's not possible to debug it with just one part of it; moreover, it's hard to help you if the code you posted does not coincide with the one that gives you problems